# Attachment resolution failure

Tags: corda

I try to use attachment in my CordApp (on Java). But when I try to create transaction I have this error `net.corda.core.contracts.AttachmentResolutionException: Attachment resolution failure for`.

My code looks like this

`final TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
                    .addInputState(oldState)
                    .addOutputState(dealState, IDEAL_CONTRACT_ID)
                    .addCommand(txCommand)
                    .addAttachment(fileHash);`

As I understand, I should download attached file to other node, but I can't find any exampls on java

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `ReceiveTransactionFlow` as a subflow when sending transactions between node. This flow receives the transaction, then resolve its dependencies and attachments before returning it.

The `CollectSignaturesFlow`/`SignTransactionFlow` pair does this automatically.